# Is it possible to model a rechargeable wallet in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Our offering allows users to maintain an online wallet, using which they can make purchases on third-party websites. We're able to use Google Analytic's Enhanced e-commerce to track purchases using [transaction measuring](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#measuring-transactions).

I'm wondering what would be the appropriate way to model this rechargeable wallet in GA, in order to track events such as wallet recharges, and ultimately reflect it in revenue reports.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a user scope custom metric for the users wallet and a custom dimension for the user's non-PII id. Enhanced e-commerce allows setting custom metrics and dimensions in all relevant actions so all the actions so you can debit the wallet and credit it based on refunds.

You can use the metric with charging event as well. Also if you have an ATM you can use the measurement protocol to update transactions.

Two caveats:

1. Client side analytics reporting is not 100% reliable. So Google Analytics will reflect aggregates and statistics fairly accurately but not at the user level.
2. Google protects privacy of site users so you will not get access to data on small segments.